# How to downgrade virtualenv from 20.4.2 to 20.0.1?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

Currently, my python version is 2.7.16 and after I run `pip install virtualenv` then I enter `python -m virtualenv venv` then I get this error msg

"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named virtualenv"

But when I run `pip freeze | grep virutalenv`, I get virtualenv==20.4.2, which is the latest version. My guess is if I downgrade virtualenv to 20.0.1 then system will recognize virtualenv, since I'm using old python version. I looked around for documents, but there were no info on how to do this.

Does anybody know how to downgrade virtualenv version from mac terminal?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
pip uninstall virtualenv

pip install virtualenv==20.0.1
```

My guess is it has to do with your python path, not at all with the version

try to `nano ~./bash_profile`
and
`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:path/to/your/venv`
then
`source ~./bash_profile`

The above is adding the path to the module to your python path so that python sees it

Comment: I think you are right. Changing virtualenv version got me same error. Thank you for this though.

Comment: the comment was a mistake, I edited the init answer

Comment: After typing export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:path/to/your/venv in nano screen, when I try to save and exit I get couple options like To Files, Mac Format, Append and Cancel. Which option do I need to select to exit with save?

Comment: It seems like ~/.bash_profile is missing to begin with. I will run touch ~/.bash_profile then go from there.

Comment: firstly don't actually write path/to/your/venv. You should find the path in which the venv package exists and go from there. Second if you don't have bash_profile maybe touching it is ok, but try to see if you have ~./profile. I edited my comment so you see its ~./ not ~/.

Comment: When you close nano just write control-X control-C and then type y for yes when it asks if you want to save